# insertAfter JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Такой вопрос у меня сегодня появился.

У меня есть функция, которая создает строки в таблице, используя цикл. То-есть в функцию приходит количество строк, и функция циклом создает строки. Но эти строки нужно добавить, так же по очереди уже в существующую таблицу, в середину. Вот код функции.

```
function genTr(count) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.setAttribute('id', 'tr' + i + '_');

        if (i == 0) {
            $('#tr' + i + '_').insertAfter("#oldtr");
        } else {
            $('#tr' + i + '_').insertAfter('#tr' + (i-1) + '_');
        }
    }
```

id - `#oldtr` - строка в таблице, после которой нужно цыклом вставлять строки.

В инспекторе ничего нет, строки не вставляються! 
Может есть решение?
Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что при получении селектора в виде строки, jQuery ищет элементы, которые **уже** есть на странице.

Так как создаваемый элемент с `id='tr' + i + '_'` еще не добавлен на страницу. селектор `$('#tr' + i + '_')` ничего не найдет, и следовательно ничего никуда не добавит.

Для решения, достаточно заменить строку, на сам созданный элемент:

```
if (i == 0) {
    $(tr).insertAfter("#oldtr");
} else {
    $(tr).insertAfter('#tr' + (i-1) + '_');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const genTr = count => {
    let newTrs = []
    let elAfter = document.getElementById('oldTr')
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      let nt = document.createElement('tr');
      nt.setAttribute('id', `id-${i}`)
      newTrs.push(nt)
    }
    newTrs.forEach((el) => {
      elAfter.after(el)
      elAfter = el
    })
  }
```